# Postgres db not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I've spend several hours figuring out how to get my database up and running. I created a new rails app and wanted to deploy it to heroku. I followed the instructions from heroku (to switch from sqlite3 -> postgresql) but it just doesn't work.

This is in my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

I can't create or seed any data in the database. Sometimes it executes the db:migrate, but even then it doesn't create anything. This is what I get when running:

```
heroku run rake db:create

FATAL: permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL: User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Does anyone has an idea on how to solve this? I don't have a clue anymore ...

Thanks!

Comment: in your Heroku dashboard. Resources -> addons. Have you added Heroku Postgres :: Database add-on ?

Comment: Yes, I added the Postgres addon!

Comment: Have you chosen a web Dyno (the one for free is ok) and activated it ?

Comment: Yes. I found a solution by re-adding the Postgres addon on heroku. Now it works fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

By default you don't need to create a db on `heroku`.
Just run `heroku run rails db:migrate` and rest of the stuff will be handled by `heroku` itself.

Also your `database.yml` should be changed to following for `Production` env.

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: myapp
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Also your rails app is by default assigned with a `Postgres addon`.
You can check this by running command `heroku addons` in the console.

Source -

1. [Heroku Getting Started Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#migrate-your-database)
2. [Heroku Postgres Addon Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)

Answer (score 3):

As per the given stacktrace, it seems like you are trying to create a database on heroku which in turn is giving you Permission Denied Error.

Firstly, you do not need to run

```
heroku run rake db:create
```

Instead run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and it should migrate the migrations which are down.

For checking the current status of migrations run the following command:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate:status
```

Other Point you mentioned:

-> I can't create or seed any data in the database
As already mentioned above you can't create a database as heroku does it for you . 
For seeding data in the database run the following command:

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a database on Heroku using db:create (you cannot drop it neither). Your database is created when you add an add-on (such as Heroku Postgres). You can only migrate and seed. And if you want to start over, you can use pg:reset (instead of drop and create)

So the correct sequence should be:

- add the Heroku add-on (such as Heroku Postgres). Add-ons are located here: https://elements.heroku.com/addons.
- rake db:migrate
- rake db:seed

if you want to start over

- rake pg:reset
- rake db:migrate
- rake db:seed

From Heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

> The PostgreSQL user your database is assigned doesn’t have permission to create or drop databases. To drop and recreate your database use pg:reset.

Comment: Thanks, I re-added the postgres addon and now it works fine! Cheers